# What does the mergeMap type definition mean?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I've inspected the mergeMap function in vscode in order to gain a deeper understanding about how it works, but I'm confused by what I think is its type definition.

```
export function mergeMap<T, O extends ObservableInput<any>>(
  project: (value: T, index: number) => O,
  concurrent?: number
): OperatorFunction<T, ObservedValueOf<O>>;
```

I'm confused that the function type definition doesn't seem to use "function type expressions" or "call signatures", which from [the typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) are the only ways I can see of defining a function type that makes sense here? Does that mean this isn't a function type definition?

I understand in javascript/typescript that functions can also have properties, I'm assuming that is what `concurrent?: number` is?

Is the `: OperatorFunction<T, ObservedValueOf<O>>;` part saying that the function type definition itself implements an interface? If so, is there a part of the typescript docs that explains how that works?

Comment: This is just a function with generic parameters which is spread over multiple lines. `concurrent?: number` is just an optional parameter. `: OperatorFunction<T, ObservedValueOf<O>>;` declares the return type.

Comment: @Unmitigated oh wow you're completely right! I don't know why I was overcomplicating things so much! Not sure if I should just delete this question?